# mysql match special character % from a text

Tags: mysql

I have to select all rows from a table where column (varchar) values contain '%' in the text.
I tried below query but failed to get correct result set.

```
SELECT * from TABLE where VALUE LIKE '%%%'
```

Above query gives all rows of the table.

Please help me to form a query to match '%' and get the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE value LIKE '%\\%%'
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f5ce3/2)

Answer (score 0):

Escape character worked for me.

```
SELECT * from TABLE where VALUE LIKE '%\%%'
```

This query gives me correct result set.

Comment: Isn't this just the same thing that is posted by @juergen d above?